# NFA to RE question

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

[image]

Converting the following NFA to Regular Expression.

**Quick question:**

Do I have to add a new initial state as Q1 is accepting an incoming edge with 0+1 from itself?

**Method used:**

State elimination method

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say "as Q1 is accepting" but isn't Q3 the only accepting state? In any case, you're asking how to convert an automaton to a regular expression and we already have a complete tutorial on that.